# SQL Server OLEDB error with no details

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, oledb

I have a SQL Server Agent job running, which uses a stored procedure to do several operations, then exports some data to an xls spreadsheet and emails that spreadsheet.  Most of the time it works, but several times a month the job fails with the error:

> OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7399).  The step failed.

Thanks, Microsoft, for the detailed error message.  Anyway, the short term fix is usually to simply re-run the job.  Usually this works, but in rarer cases it does not, and I must restart the SQL Server instance.

Here is how my code interacts with OLEDB:

```
    Insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 5.0;Database=\\Excel\POStatus\POStatus.xls;', 
   'SELECT * FROM [POStatus$]')  

Select --Tons of columns with tons of math and functions
FROM --5 tables joined together (left joins)
WHERE -- Tons of where conditions
Order by --Case statement for custom sorting

Set @vCommand =  'copy \\Excel\POStatus\POStatus.xls \\Excel\POStatus\POStatus_' + @vDate + '.xls'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @vCommand , NO_OUTPUT

... omitted for brevity...

  Set @nvSubject = ' POStatus ' + @vDate
  Set @nvMessage = ' This is an automated message, please respond to the IS department,  thank you ' 
  Set @nvMessage = @nvMessage + char(13) + char(10)

      Set @nvAttachments = '\\Excel\POStatus\POStatus_' + @vDate + '.xls'

      Exec master..xp_sendmail 
           @recipients = @nvRecipients , @copy_recipients = @nvCopy_recipients ,
           @subject = @nvSubject , @message = @nvMessage ,  
           @query = @nvQuery , @width = @iWidth , @attachments = @nvAttachments
```

So, what is the cause of this, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Does the copy succeed? It might be worth turning off `NO_OUTPUT` on `xp_cmdshell` to find out :-)

Comment: You mean, does the copy succeed when the entire operation fails?  That I don't know.  But I'll check next time the failure occurs.

Answer (score 0):

When you call OPENROWSET, it load the DLL for OLEDB provider for Excel. These operations happens inside the SQL Server Stack memory. When a lot of call to older DLL (ActiveX/COM) are made, it's not impossible that your stack might get full. You can resolve this in 2 ways:

1) You make these operations outside a TSQL code. You can use a SSIS package for example but you have to change your code not to use OPENROWSET. You can use the DTS Wizard to do most of the job. This is my personnal recommandation !

2) You can also set SQL Server to have a bigger memory Stack by using the -g command parameter. I think 256 MB is the default and you can set it to 512. To do that you need to open the SQL Server Configuration Manager. Depending on your version, you should have a place to change the "Startup Parameters"

Comment: OpenRowSet is not GOOD or BAD. We just need to be aware of the difference of OLEDB in-memory process with .NET out-of-memory process.

Comment: Ok, so when is OPENROWSET safer to use, and when is it not?

Comment: I suggest using OPENROWSET when you can control the number of calls. Say you have to load a file for an installation or migration. You know it will be done only one time or so. It's not a good idea to use it a process everyone can call it manually. Also, in your particular case, your query result must be huge. I'm not sure how much memory will be used by it but it might get bigger than the 256 MB of stack. You can use the option "Include Client Statistics" in SSMS to know more about your query result size in MB.